# Can we create a fact from inside the Prolog code?

Tags: list, prolog

My aim is to break the given list of lists in such a way that I am able to access the individual lists by the same name. I have the following list:-

```
mylist([[1,2],[2,3],[3,4],[4,6]]).
```

I want to break the list into [1,2], [2,3], [3,4], [4,6] so that I can access the items (like [1,2]) individually.

For that, can I create a new fact from the separated list elements? I am able to separate the elements into individual lists. But, I want to convert those individual lists into facts. Like:-

```
mylist([[1,2],[2,3],[3,4],[4,6]]).
```

should become the following:-

```
node([1,2]).
node([2,3]).
node([3,4]).
node([4,6]).
```

And then I should be able to access each and every list using "node".

Comment: See `assertz/1` as well as compile time term expansion, with `term_expansion/2`

Answer (score 1):

The other answer is fine (esp. the `forall` solution), but here is what you could do if you knew your list at compile time, and wanted to add the `node/1` facts to the database at compile time.

This code is simplified from the example available at the very bottom of [this page](http://eu.swi-prolog.org/pldoc/man?section=strings):

In your file (I will call it nodes.pl):

```
term_expansion(nodes_list(NL), Nodes) :-
        maplist(to_node, NL, Nodes).

to_node(X, node(X)).

nodes_list([[1,2],[2,3],[3,4],[4,6]]).
```

When I consult the file, I get:

```
?- [nodes].
true.

?- listing(node).
node([1, 2]).
node([2, 3]).
node([3, 4]).
node([4, 6]).

true.
```

Two details:

1. The expanded predicate, here `nodes_list/1`, is **not** going to be in the database.
2. The clause of `term_expansion/2` **must come before** the definition of `nodes_list/1` in the source file.

Answer (score 0):

A great answer (maybe the best) recommended(in the comments) by CapelliC is:

```
?-forall(member(X,[[1,2],[2,3],[3,4]]),assertz(node(X))).
```

You could also write:

```
my_list(L):- member(X,L),assertz(node(X)).
```

Example:

```
?- my_list([[1,2],[2,3],[3,4]]).
true ;
true ;
true.
?- node([1,2]).
true ;
false.
```

Another way thanks to  CapelliC's recommendation would be:

```
?- maplist(X>>assertz(node(X)), [[1,2],[2,3],[3,4]]).
```

Comment: possibly: '?- maplist(X>>assertz(node(X)), [[1,2],[2,3],[3,4]]).`

Comment: Yes that's a great implementation thanks for pointing that out I will edit the answer.

Comment: `?-forall(member(X,[[1,2],[2,3],[3,4]]),assertz(node(X))).` would be far more portable, and practically efficient like the lambda+maplist solution

Comment: Thanks again, I didn't think using forall/2 thanks!!

Comment: You should put the `forall` solution at the top, it is the most idiomatic way to achieve it. You can also see [here](http://eu.swi-prolog.org/pldoc/doc_for?object=forall/2) for a bit more explanation, and an example with `assertz`.

Comment: Thanks Boris for the useful information I will edit now the answer, thanks!!